# Cloudera Docker image - not able to access Hue & Cloudera manager

Tags: cloudera, hue, cloudera-manager

I've installed Cloudera Docker on Mac (referred link - https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/12/docker-is-the-new-quickstart-option-for-apache-hadoop-and-cloudera/)

Command used for starting Cloudera Docker image ->

```
docker run --privileged=true --hostname=quickstart.cloudera -t -i <image_hash> /usr/bin/docker-quickstart -p 80:80 -p 8888:8888 -p 7180:7180
```

I've re-started Hue (successfully) using command :

```
service hue start
```

Also, i started Cloudera Manager (successfully), using command :

```
/home/cloudera/cloudera-manager --express --force
```

However, when i try to access Cloudera Manager or Hue using UI, it doesnt show up
(url cannot be found)

urls i tried :

```
http://localhost:7180
http://localhost:8888
http://quickstart.cloudera:7180
http://quickstart.cloudera:8888
```

what do i need to do to access this ?

Also, i was trying to check if there is any other port is allocated by dockers

command ->

```
docker port quizzical_kowalevski // quizzical_kowalevski - name of the container
```

This shows up nothing :(

Pls note - This is on my local m/c (Mac)

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
7b2d26270435        4239cd2958c6        "/usr/bin/docker-qui…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            sharp_bohr
```

Error logs (for hue) :

```
[29/Nov/2018 01:42:20 ] supervisor   ERROR    Exception in supervisor main loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/supervisor.py", line 386, in main
    wait_loop(sups, options)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/supervisor.py", line 396, in wait_loop
    time.sleep(1)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/supervisor.py", line 218, in sig_handler
    raise SystemExit("Signal %d received. Exiting" % signum)
SystemExit: Signal 15 received. Exiting
```

Comment: Can you post /var/log/hue/error.log?

Comment: And are you running docker directly on your mac OS or inside a VM?

Comment: Also add a `docker ps` output

Comment: @AlexandreJuma - in /var/log/hue/errr.log                  [29/Nov/2018 01:42:20 ] supervisor   ERROR    Exception in supervisor main loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/supervisor.py", line 386, in main
    wait_loop(sups, options)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/supervisor.py", line 396, in wait_loop
    time.sleep(1)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/supervisor.py", line 218, in sig_handler
    raise SystemExit("Signal %d received. Exiting" % signum)
SystemExit: Signal 15 received. Exiting

Comment: docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
7b2d26270435        4239cd2958c6        "/usr/bin/docker-qui…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            sharp_bohr

Comment: updated the error logs & output of - docker ps in description

Comment: You don't seem to have any port definition based on your `docker ps` output. Please try this: `docker run --hostname=quickstart.cloudera 
--restart unless-stopped 
--privileged=true -dti 
-p 8888:8888 -p 80:80 
-p 7180:7180 
cloudera/quickstart 
/usr/bin/docker-quickstart`

Comment: I've provided an answer based on your inputs. Clearly seem to be the order of the switches. You are sending "-p 80:80 -p 8888:8888 -p 7180:7180" (which configures the container port mapping) as arguments to the cloudera application because you've put them in the end of the command. Please see the answer and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your input, the docker run command is malformed.

You shouldn't add additional switches (in this case port mapping switches) after the image identification and command to start the containerized application. All additional arguments will be passed as arguments of the containerized application (i.e: to /usr/bin/docker-quickstart instead of being taken up by the docker engine to configure the port mapping)

Your output of `docker ps` show that you have no port mapping definition because of this.

You can read more about `docker run` command [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#general-form). The general form of the `docker run` command is:

```
$ docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

You should change the order of your switches to something like this:

```
docker run --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --restart unless-stopped --privileged=true -dti -p 8888:8888 -p 80:80 -p 7180:7180 cloudera/quickstart /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
```